# Беды с инкапсуляцией или с башкой у C#-а? Загадочное изменение переменной списка

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-7, c#-7.3

Для меня эта ситуация считается чуть ли не **паронормальной**. Ну, или у меня проблемы (с башкой или с, хм, с ПК)

Моя C# прога - это некий движок для 2д платформера. Изначально движок запускал цикл, который вызывал методы у всех игровых объектов(Objs.Obj) в списке. Это работало хорошо, пока я не захотел изменить список в методе одного из объектов, и тогда справедливо возникла ошибка изменения списка во время его использования. Я усложнил класс списка игровых объектов и получил, казалось, ту штуку, которая должна была идеально работать...(Далее пойдёт подробное описание работы и использования кода ниже)

У меня, в моём статическом классе ObjList есть поле actualContent - список игровых объектов, который изменяется только при использовании метода UpdateContent(), который во время использования списка никогда не изменялся. Таким образом, именно это поле возвращается при методе GetContent(). Есть методы SetContent() и AddContent(), один заменяет весь список, другой лишь добавляет игровой объект, но общее у них то, что они меняют только поле newContent, к которому и приравнивается actualContent при вызове метода UpdateContent().

```
static class ObjList
    {
        private static List<Objs.Obj> actualContent;

        private static List<Objs.Obj> newContent;

        public static List<Objs.Obj> GetContent() => actualContent;

        public static void SetContent(List<Objs.Obj> objList) => newContent = objList;

        public static void AddContent(Objs.Obj obj) => newContent.Add(obj);

        public static void UpdateContent() => actualContent = newContent;

    }
```

Ну, так вот. **Это не работает.**
[image]

Возможностью изменить actualContent хоть как-то, кроме как с помощью метода UpdateContent() нет, ибо это поле приватное. Но вот сама паранормальщина: Проследив с помощью брейкпоинтов на момент изменения поля, я увидел, как во время исполнения метода SetContent() или AddContent(), изменился newContent(что логично), но вместе с ним **каким-то способом изменился и actualContent**
В данной ситуации, полагаю, хорошим тоном было бы указать версии некоторых используемых программ: Visual Studio 2017, C# 7.3 .NET Framework v4.6.1

Comment: ну так после присваивания `actualContent = newContent` обе переменные ссылаются на один и тот же список. Как минимум в этот момент нужно заново инициализировать `newContent`, либо присваивать копию

Comment: Так... это уже можно считать ответом. Т.е., если одна переменная списка приравнивается к другой, то она не берёт её копию а берёт один и тот же экземпляр? Что ж, пинки незнаний фундаментальных вещей дают о себе знать. Спасибо тебе. Если это так, то моя проблема, кажись, решена.

Comment: Да, по сути ты присвоил ссылку на список, и теперь у тебя две ссылки указывающие на один и тот же объект, поэтому при изменении его, будет видно в обоих случаях

Answer (score 1):

В этом примере та переменная списка, что приравнивается к той переменной списка, которая изменяется - впоследствии изменяется вместе с ней, так как обе эти переменные равны одному и тому же экземпляру класса List, а потому связаны.
Так, в этом примере мне просто нужно заменить строку

```
public static void UpdateContent() => actualContent = newContent;
```

на вот такую

```
public static void UpdateContent() => actualContent = new List<Objs.Obj>(newContent);
```

Таким образом мы берём и копируем тот список.
**Большое спасибо за фактический ответ в комментариях от Grundy**

Comment: можно было не делать общим